# What does this string of code: gr.sys_id[key] = current.getValue(glideElement.getName());

Tags: copy, key, duplicates, servicenow

I'm trying to copy (duplicate) a record in ServiceNow table of incidents, but can not make this string work: gr.sys_id[key] = current.getValue(glideElement.getName());

The goal is to copy all fields values except sys_id.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide the entire script (or enough to provide context). Where is this running (e.g. business rule)? What are the variables being initialized to (e.g. where are you getting glideElement)? The call to gr.sys_id[key] is not doing what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the UI Action `Insert & Stay` which is kind of a Duplicate Script.

You can use the same functionality in your Business rule or any other server side script:

```
doInsertAndStay();
function doInsertAndStay() {
    var saveMe = current;
    if (typeof current.number != 'undefined' && current.number){
        current.number = ""; // generate a new number
    }

    current.insert();
    action.setRedirectURL(saveMe);
}
```

The GlideRecord function `insert()` duplicates a record and of course a new sys_id is used for the new record. As far as I know you are not able to define the sys_id by your self.

Comment: Mentioned answer is the best solution to do it.